# How to link to the settings page of an Android app in ionic

Tags: capacitor

### Problem

I am trying to request permissions for notifications from the user. As `androidPermissions.requestPermission` does not work as intended, I would like to show an alert with a link in it or forward the user with the click on a button to the native settings page, where he can deny or allow notifications for the app. So basically a screen outside the app. How can I do this? Is it even possible?

Comment: I would check one of the plugins here: https://github.com/capacitor-community/proposals/issues/103